# ruby, evaluation multiple conditions in an array

Tags: ruby

So maybe I have this all wrong, but I'm sure there is a way to do this, say I have a an `if` statement, that I want to return `true` if all the conditions in an array evaluate as true.

say I have this:

```
def real_visitor?(location, request, params)

  valid_location = [
    params['referrer'] == 'us',
    params['bot'] != 'googlebot',
    5 + 5 == 10 
  ]

  if valid_location
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

How would I evaluate each of the conditions in the array `valid_location`, some of those conditions in that array are just pseudocode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array#any?` or `Array#all?`. It's like putting the `||` or `&&` operator between all your conditions, but it doesn't do short-circuit evaluation, which is sometimes useful.

```
return valid_location.all?
```

You don't need the `return` keyword, by the way. I'd leave it out.

Comment: In MRI 1.8.7, `all?` and `any?` short-circuit: `all?` stops at the first falsy value; `any?` stops at the first truthy value.

Comment: Well an example of what I mean is that `[puts("1"), puts("2")].all?` would print both "1" and "2", but `puts("1") && puts("2")` would only print "1", even though the semantics are the same. The items in the array are being evaluated *before* `all?` is being called.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the great explanation.